# Open HTML file when java program start

Tags: java, html

I'm currently trying to create a very small game in Java, right now I don't know much about Java. Is it possible to open and show and HTML file, like a start up menu?

Example:

1. Jframe starts
2. Html file (menu) menu.html
3. Depends on choice - levels.html - settings.html and exit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display very simple html pages (nothing too fancy with CSS3, Javascript and stuff) within a JScrollPane.

```
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane();
js.getViewport().add(tp);
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
jf.getContentPane().add(js);
jf.pack();
jf.setSize(800,800);
jf.setVisible(true); 

try {
  URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
  tp.setPage(url);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also use html pages within a jar file and load them like this:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("contents.html");
tp.setPage(url);
```

You can react on links within the ScrollPane using the HyperlinkListener.
There is a more sufisticated tutorial on this on http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/HyperlinkListenerExample.htm

Happy coding :)